# Prove $(P^{−1} + B^TR^{−1}B)^{−1}B^TR^{−1} = PB^T (BP B^T + R)^{−1} $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove the following matrix identity

$(P^{−1} + B^TR^{−1}B)^{−1}B^TR^{−1} = PB^T (BP B^T + R)^{−1} $

where $P ∈ \mathbb R^{N×N}$ , $B ∈ \mathbb R
^{M×N}$ , and $R ∈ \mathbb R
^{M×M}$. $P$ and $R$ are invertible.
Note that if M  N, it will be much cheaper to evaluate the right-hand side
than the left-hand side.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: It suffices to prove that $B^TR^{−1}(BP B^T + R) = (P^{−1} + B^TR^{−1}B)\, PB^T$ or $B^TR^{−1}BP B^T + B^T = B^T + B^TR^{−1}BPB^T$.

Comment: what does *"Note that if M  N, it will be much cheaper to evaluate the right-hand side
than the left-hand side"* mean? You seem to be missing an inequality.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Use the **THEOREM 2.1** below. Theorem whose proof you can find [here](http://msvlab.hre.ntou.edu.tw/grades/now/inte/Inverse%20&%20Border/border-LuTT.pdf).
[image]